# True or False: Polynomial has non-trivial solution in $Q_p$ iff has non-trivial solution in $Z_p$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For polynomials, it is true that it has non-trivial solution in $Q_p$ iff it has non-trivial solution in $Z_p$?
It seems to be true for homogenous polynomials, but seems not true for non-homogenous case.

For example, Suppose $x^2=2$ has $a=p^{-n}b$ where $b \in Z_p$ as solution in $Q_p$. Then it only shows $x^2=2p^{2n}$ has non-trivial solution in $Z_p$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you talking about multivariate polynomials? Or just in one variable - in which case I guess you want monic polynomials, at the very least!

Comment: As written this is false. The polynomial $px - 1$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ but has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: It is true for *monic* polynomials with $\mathbb{Z}_p$-coefficients. For such polynomials, a root lies in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ iff it lies in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin By saying monic, do you mean monic one variable polynomial? ... And in my example $a^2=2$. Suppose $a=a_{0}p^{-n}+a_{1}p^{-n+1}+...$, then $(a_{0}+a_{1}p+a_{2}p^{2}...)^2=2p^{2n}$, how do I show $a_{0}, a_{1}...a_{n-1}$ are all $0$?

Comment: @Mathmo123... Ok...Let me restricted to two cases 'monic and one-variable',  and 'monic and multivariable' Do they both satisfy the desired property: having a non-trivial solution in $Z_p$ iff having a non-trivial solution in $Q_p$?

Comment: @DouglasMolin Ok... I think I know how to do it... comparing constant terms and so $a_0=0$, then dividing $p^2$ on both sides and continue

Comment: @DouglasMolin Can you find a proof about this statement (given monic polynomial with $Z_p$ coefficients, a root in $Q_p$ iff in $Z_p$)? Is that mean $Z_p$ being integrally closed?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a PID and therefore integrally closed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, this is true for monic polynomials in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$. In other words, a polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$ with $a_i\in\mathbb Z_p$ has a solution in $\mathbb Q_p$ if and only if $\mathbb Z_p$. This is exactly the statement that $\mathbb Z_p$ is [integrally closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrally_closed_domain).

To see this, suppose $\beta\in\mathbb Q_p$ is a root, and suppose for a contradiction that $v(\beta)<0$. Then a simple calculation shows$$-\beta=a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_0\beta^{1-n}.$$
Here, $v(-\beta)<0$ so $-\beta\notin\mathbb Z_p$, while clearly $a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_0\beta^{1-n}\in\mathbb Z_p$ since $\beta^{-1}\in\mathbb Z_p$.